# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReader' of undefined

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, openai-api

When trying to stream the response of a fetch request, I get the following error: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReader' of undefined".`

More specifically, I'm trying to use the OpenAI API, and am using standard code for streaming a ChatGPT response found online (e.g. [this site](https://www.builder.io/blog/stream-ai-javascript#query-dom-elements)). Please see the code below:

```
const API_KEY = "..."; // Private key goes here

const API_URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";

const getResponse = async () => {
  try {
    // Fetch data from openai as a post request
    fetch(API_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages: [
          {
            role: "system",
            content: "10 words sentence",
          },
        ],
      }),
      stream: true,
    });

    const reader = response.body.getReader(); // <-- Problem is here

    ...

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

I was able to successfully get a response (with a delay) when `stream: false`, so the issue isn't with calling the API.

Logging `typeof response.body` to the console yields `undefined`, which matches the error.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27741